# Mongo Query on hystrix thread

Tags: spring, mongodb, hystrix

My service first calls remote service(using hystrix with default values v.1.5.18 thread pool) and then saves response to MongoDb. My problem is that query to MongoDB runs on hystrix thread pool and I don't know why. Could you give me some advice why is that or I can verify it?